# How could I have known not to go here?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, minesweeper

[image: minesweeper]

How could I have known not to press where the red bomb is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2 just above and to the left of that mine only has one flag next to it, and all the other cells around it are cleared.